# What is the on-premise equivalent of an Azure key vault?

Tags: azure-keyvault, secret-key, aws-secrets-manager

As I am a programmer with solely experience with production environments in the cloud that run with a cloud-based **secret manager**, I was wondering: How are secrets managed in an on-premise instance? I bet they are not just written in the **application settings** or the OS **environment variables**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

•   There is no equivalent of azure key vault in on premises environment though you can use ADCS (Active directory certificate services) for certificate shared secret management in on premises infrastructure for authorizing and authenticating resources, service principal names and other identity attributes.

•   Though for the handling of the cryptographic keys used by the cloud apps and services hosted on premises, we can setup app key vaults for business central on-premises server as well. Please refer the below official documentation for your reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/setup-app-key-vault-onprem

This document articulates the steps and processes to undertake for integrating the functionality of Azure key vault in your on-premises environment.

•   Though, if you want to directly use the Azure key vault’s functionality in your on-premises infrastructure environment, you can provide internet access to your on-premises resources and use client certificate authentication and IP restrictions with key vault through a VPN tunnel for additional security.

Please refer the below links for more information: -

[secret management in on premise application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65092721/secret-management-in-on-premise-application)